# displaying folder content as image gallery within the CMS

Tags: piranha-cms

I want to display the content of a folder with piranha cms... How do I do this?

Can I do this inside of the CMS or do I need to create something special?

I have looked at this..

http://piranhacms.org/listing-images-located-in-a-specific-folder

figure it out.. there doesn't appear to a pagemodel in my project.

Comment: Hi there! The link you provided is perfectly valid for displaying images from a media folder on a CMS controlled page. The class PageModel is located in the namespace `Piranha.Models`. If you need more help you need to clarify more what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: are cheers man... that's cool thank you!